# Print 2 different patterns from a string on one line

Tags: awk

I have a file with strings like one below.

```
F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315
```

The strings are demarcated by markers in this case the "F" and a number. In this case the markers are `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, `F4`, `F5`, `F6`, and `F7`.

I would like to print the 5 characters following `F2` and the 6 characters following `F6` separated by a space so that the result is

```
B3094 BC313D
```

Here is my attempt though it prints in two lines instead of one. How would like both values on one line.

```
$ echo F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315 | \
   awk '{match($0,/F2/); print substr($0, RSTART +2, RLENGTH +3);} \
        {match($0,/F6/); print substr($0, RSTART +2,RLENGTH +4);}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're super close to a working solution.  Here is one way to do it (formatted for readability):

```
awk '{
    match($0,/F2/); 
    a=substr($0, RSTART +2, RLENGTH +3); 
    match($0,/F6/); 
    b=substr($0, RSTART +2,RLENGTH +4);
    print a" "b
}'
```

In this case, I'm taking your two `substr()` functions and assigning them to variables, instead of printing them directly, and then just setting them to print at the same time at the end.  By printing them in a single print call, `awk` only adds a single newline character at the end of the line, rather than after each part of the line, which is what was splitting your result into two lines.

```
bash:~$ echo F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315 | awk '{match($0,/F2/); a=substr($0, RSTART +2, RLENGTH +3); match($0,/F6/); b=substr($0, RSTART +2,RLENGTH +4); print a" "b}'
B3094 BC313D
```

Comment: ... or just `print a,b` since the default OFS is a single space

Comment: Thanks Tim and steeldiver for the solutions. They work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the `Fn` markers are ordered, then you could use them as field separators:

```
echo 'F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315' | 
    awk -F'(F2|F6)' '{print substr($2,1,5), substr($3,1,6)}'
B3094 BC313D
```

or, splitting on all the `Fn` markers and numbering the fields accordingly

```
echo 'F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315' | 
    awk -F'F[0-9]' '{print substr($3,1,5), substr($7,1,6)}'
B3094 BC313D
```

(in this case you may not need the `substr` at all, if you just want everything up to the next `Fn` - it's not clear from your problem description).

With GNU Awk, you could capture both substrings in a single pattern and access them via the optional `match` array:

```
echo 'F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315' | 
    gawk 'match($0, /F2(.{5}).*F6(.{6})/, a) {print a[1], a[2]}'
B3094 BC313D
```

Alternatively, with Perl you could capture the characters after the markers using lookbehinds:

```
echo 'F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315' | 
    perl -lne 'print join " ", /(?<=F2).{5}|(?<=F6).{6}/g'
B3094 BC313D
```

or

```
echo 'F1B308F2B3094F3B310F4B317CF5B312F6BC313DF7B315' | 
    perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if /(?<=F2)(.{5}).*?(?<=F6)(.{6})/g'
B3094 BC313D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne ' $, = $"; print /(?=.*F2(.{5}))(?=.*F6(.{6}))/' input-file.txt
```

The above shall , irrespective of whichever, `F2` or `F6` comes earlier on in the current record, will print the following digits of `F2` then those of `F6`.

`$, = OFS` `$" = double quoted separator = single space`